# How to convert a list multi-nested dictionaries to a pandas DataFrame and transform the DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to convert a list of nested dictionaries (game_stats) to a pandas DataFrame. I have tried to do so with "games_stats_df" but I am getting a DataFrame with "id" and then a list of dictionaries again.

```
print(game_stats)

[{'id': 401282099,
 'teams': [{'conference': 'SEC',
            'homeAway': 'away',
            'points': 21,
            'school': 'LSU',
            'stats': [{'category': 'rushingTDs', 'stat': '2'},
                      {'category': 'passingTDs', 'stat': '1'},
                      {'category': 'kickingPoints', 'stat': '3'},
                      {'category': 'fumblesRecovered', 'stat': '0'},
                      {'category': 'firstDowns', 'stat': '22'}]},
           {'conference': 'SEC',
            'homeAway': 'home',
            'points': 42,
            'school': 'Kentucky',
            'stats': [{'category': 'rushingTDs', 'stat': '3'},
                      {'category': 'passingTDs', 'stat': '4'},
                      {'category': 'kickingPoints', 'stat': '0'},
                      {'category': 'fumblesRecovered', 'stat': '1'},
                      {'category': 'firstDowns', 'stat': '24'}]}]}]
```

```
game_stats_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([game.to_dict() for game in game_stats])
print(game_stats_df.head())

          id                                              teams
0  401282099  [{'school': 'LSU', 'conference': 'SEC', 'homeA...
```

Ideally, I am trying to get a DataFrame with the below format:

```
game_id    school   conference  homeAway    points  rushingTDs  passingTDs  etc
401282099   LSU      SEC          away       21        2            1
```

Comment: You'll need to reformat your data because you have 3 levels of nested list of dicts. The last level (`stats`) will be easy, for the rest I'm not sure, can you provide a bit longer `game_stats` data, containing at least two items per list ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_normalize`:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(game_stats, 'teams', 'id').explode('stats').reset_index()
df = pd.concat([df, pd.json_normalize(df.pop('stats'))], axis=1)
df = df.pivot_table('stat', df.columns[1:-2].tolist(), 'category').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
category conference homeAway  points    school         id  firstDowns  fumblesRecovered  kickingPoints  passingTDs  rushingTDs
0               SEC     away      21       LSU  401282099        22.0               0.0            3.0         1.0         2.0
1               SEC     home      42  Kentucky  401282099        24.0               1.0            0.0         4.0         3.0
```

Comment: Execute each line of code separately to view the transformation of the dataframe to the final output.

Comment: Thank you! However, I am now getting the error "TypeError: 'TeamGame' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: There is no 'TeamGame' in your sample.